# Django Cannot update a query once a slice has been taken

Tags: python, django

I have a query...

```
message_batch = Message.objects.all()[500]
```

I don't want to have to make another database call to retrieve the objects, besides I already have them in memory so whats the point.

So I tried to update like this:

```
message_batch.update(send_date=datetime.datetime.now(), status="Sent")
```

But I get the following error message:

**Cannot update a query once a slice has been taken.**

Why? Is there a around around this? I want to update the objects I already have in memory not make another call to retrieve them.

This is my full code, has to be way around this....

```
total = Message.objects.filter(status="Unsent", sender=user,   batch=batch).exclude(recipient_number__exact='').count()

for i in xrange(0,total,500):
    message_batch = Message.objects.filter(status="Unsent").exclude(recipient_number__exact='')[i:i+500]
    # do some stuff here
    # once all done update the objects
    message_batch.update(send_date=datetime.datetime.now(), billed=True)
```

Comment: use django-memcached to do it . it can be helpfull

Comment: The workaround would be to make django _evaluate_ the queryset before the slice. Something like `message_batch = Message.objects.all()` and then `count = len(message_batch)` and then `message_batch = message_batch[:500].update(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update objects by their primary keys:

```
base_qs = Message.objects.filter(status="Unsent", sender=user, batch=batch).exclude(recipient_number__exact='')
total = base_qs.count()

for i in xrange(0, total, 500):
    page = list(base_qs[i:i+500])
    page_ids = [o.pk for o in page]
    # Do some stuff here
    base_qs.filter(pk__in=page_ids).update(send_date=datetime.datetime.now(), billed=True)
```

Comment: This will send commit to database every time you use update, performance will suffer a lot if you have a lot of entries to be updated. Use transactions as on my answer.

Comment: Question is how to use QuerySet after slicing, not how to optimize SQL queries. You can always wrap above code with `commit_on_success`.

Answer (score 2):

Use django database transactions for best performance:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/

eg:

```
from django.db import transaction

total = Message.objects.filter(status="Unsent", sender=user, batch=batch).exclude(recipient_number__exact='').count()

    for i in xrange(0,total,500):
        message_batch = Message.objects.filter(status="Unsent").exclude(recipient_number__exact='')[i:i+500]
        # do some stuff here
        #once all done update the objects
        message_batch.update(send_date=datetime.datetime.now(), billed=True)

        with transaction.commit_on_success():
            for m in message_batch:
                m.update(send_date=datetime.datetime.now(), billed=True)
```

This will wrap eg. 5000 rows update in to one call to database instead of calling to database for 5000 times if you execute update not in a transaction.