# How to put limit on django orm update query with order by

Tags: django, django-models, sql-update, limit

I have to put limit on the number of records to update in Django ORM Model object.

I have tried:

```
CustomObject.objects.filter(column_x='XXX').update(column_y='YYY')[:10]
```

but slicing is not allowed with update.

I don't want to fetch the id separately and using those ids for update as the number of records is very large ( 1 million to 80 million ).

Interested in the hitting the DB once.

Answer (score 7):

Use nested querying:

```
nested_q = CustomObject.objects.filter(column_x='XXX')[:10]
CustomObject.objects.filter(pk__in=nested_q).update(column_y='YYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, as for ids, you don't have to load all records once, load a slice, updated it and then next slice. see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18469592/2074398).